# Maven upgrade source version

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

I have a problem. I installed Java 15.0.2 on my Ubuntu machine:

```
java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I also installed maven:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 15.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.0-66-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Now When I am trying to build the package, I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project Simulator: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /binance/Simulator/src/main/java/com/company/drivers/SimulatorDriver.java:[241,16] switch expressions are not supported in -source 7
[ERROR]   (use -source 14 or higher to enable switch expressions)
[ERROR] /binance/Simulator/src/main/java/com/company/drivers/SimulatorDriver.java:[242,22] switch rules are not supported in -source 7
[ERROR]   (use -source 14 or higher to enable switch rules)
[ERROR] /binance/Simulator/src/main/java/com/company/models/Candlestick.java:[127,43] method references are not supported in -source 7
[ERROR]   (use -source 8 or higher to enable method references)
[ERROR] /binance/Simulator/src/main/java/com/company/models/Candlestick.java:[175,155] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7
[ERROR]   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
[ERROR] /binance/Simulator/src/main/java/com/company/models/Slope.java:[63,38] method references are not supported in -source 7
[ERROR]   (use -source 8 or higher to enable method references)
[ERROR] /binance/Simulator/src/main/java/com/company/models/Slope.java:[94,155] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7
[ERROR]   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
[ERROR] /binance/Simulator/src/main/java/com/company/models/Pattern.java:[76,35] method references are not supported in -source 7
[ERROR]   (use -source 8 or higher to enable method references)
[ERROR] /binance/Simulator/src/main/java/com/company/models/Pattern.java:[102,155] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7
[ERROR]   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
[ERROR] /binance/Simulator/src/main/java/com/company/deserializers/AgentStrategyConfigDeserializer.java:[21,163] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7
[ERROR]   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
[ERROR] /binance/Simulator/src/main/java/com/company/deserializers/AgentStrategyPackageDeserializer.java:[27,163] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7
[ERROR]   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

It looks like that the Java version in Maven is 7, but I need to run at version 15. I already installed java, but how can I upgrade/set the java for my maven?

Comment: Maven tells javac to behave as it did in Java 7.  Modern versions of javac cannot anymore.  The default setting in maven might be argued to be lifted to 17 when that version comes out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the following to your POM

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>15</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add these properties in your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.release>15</maven.compiler.release>
    <java.version>15</java.version>
</properties>
```